Dog uses doggie door perfectly during day even when home alone but not at night!
Our three year old dog uses doggy door perfectly during the day even when home alone but at night just wees and sometimes poos inside. Doesn’t matter if we take away water early and take long walk and she uses toilet on the walk she will still go in house during night. Now our other dog has started copying her. Have tried everything that has been recommended to us and paid so much money on what’s been recommended anti anxiety sprays etc and just at a loss! Any one had same experience? Help please!

Does this answer your question? Dog won't go outside at night to pee

This is just a wild guess: Do you have any lights on inside? Even a tiny light source may prevent you from seeing what's outside the door. Just turn on a light and try looking out the window at night to see what I mean, you'll just see your own reflection. Maybe having lights in your garden, or making it darker inside could help.

This is a surprisingly common issue for many dogs.
I am a pro dog walker and have a client who is at wits end for the very same reason. Her 8 year old schnauzer can use the dog door, but doesn't at night. The owner will even get up many times to let the dog outside the door to pee on the grass, but it just chooses not to. Then she wakes up and it has gone pee or poo in the house on her expensive rugs and polished wood floor.
Things to note are that the only move house to this new neighborhood 3 years ago. The dog had a LOT of anxiety around the move, even six weeks before the move. The owner lives by herself with the one dog. So that dog is taking in all of her movements and behaviors as directed at him. In the park he is very adventurous and brave. Shows no sign of fear.
He has even begun digging large holes under the hedges in the back yard, but doesn't bury anything. Her best guess is that he is afraid of the noises of the possums at night.
These are the three things I have recommended that she use (as I know that they have worked for other people.
1   She trialed anti-anxiety drugs on the dog before, but like for humans, it can take time to get the exact match of chemical for the dog's brain. You dont want to dumb the dog down, have it drowsy, just less reactive to noises etc.
Possums are protected by law in our local community,  but yes bright auto lights might help, as long as they dont shine into the neighbours. But dogs have very sensitive hearing, so the issue of other animals could be far away from the yard.
2   How a person speaks to their dog and corrects their dog can have a profound effect on their relationship. The dog appears to becoming more needy at home, and the owner has had to stop it jumping on the bed at night and putting its paws and nose on her head when she is sleeping.
If the advice she has read hasnt helped, I have recommended a good dog behaviorist, but the owner needs to take on the advice and try the actions for a while to see if they can change the unwanted behaviors (territory marking, or just scared of going outside at night).
3  While older dogs who have never been crate trained can hate confined spaces, it plus anti anxiety meds might be part of the solution at night time.
The issue you are having might not have all of these problems, but unless the dog has a physical or mental issue that is undiagnosed, it can often be the relationship it perceives its having with its owner. I just provide advice to my clients to try and make both their lives better, leaving judgement out of it as much as i can.  Hope some of these solutions give you options.

It sounds like she's scared to go out alone at night. I know I've had pets that won't go out at night unless I go with them. Turn on the lights outside when she goes out and/or install motion-activated lights so she can see and isn't as scared.
Another option is to build positive association with the outside during night by playing with her out there, feeding her out there, etc.

can you update your answer and tell a bit about how you solved the problem,as your answer is now it looks like it should have been a comment to the OP`s question.
